# New Quicktime Look for Embedded mp3s

Tags: javascript, xhtml, osx-snow-leopard, embed, quicktime

With the release of Snow Leopard, Apple has also unveiled a newer, slicker looking version of the quicktime controls for when html links to an mp3. I'm working on a site with embedded mp3s, and would like them to show up inside Quicktime's newer skin, but I can't figure out how to do it. Everything I've tried results in the same older gray skin. Interestingly enough however, if I simply link to the mp3 file, so it opens in a new window instead of embedding it directly in the page, the newer skin appears. Does apple have a new codebase implemented for this new skin that I can use, or is there some other way to embed mp3s with this newer skin?

Does anyone even know what I'm talking about? Any help would, as always, be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

PS: Upon inspecting apple site more closely, they seem to be able to do what I'm talking about, though looking at the site's source was no help. If you go to http://www.apple.com and, on the main page, click "Watch the iMac Video", it streams a movie using the new quicktime skin. Still no clue on how to implement it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone here is interested, I just found a website with a tutorial to implement the new Apple Quicktime X look:

http://www.jutix-production.com/tutoriel-apple-quicktime-x-web-player.php

It's in french, so you need to use a translator, but it's all there. Works great!

Answer (score 2):

Apple's site fakes it. Try it on a computer without QuickTime X and you'll see — that's a Javascript-based interface designed to look like the QuickTime X interface. I don't know of any way to tell QuickTime to use the new interface for embedded content. You might be able to fake it by creating an iframe that uses the media file as its src. It's a bit of a fragile solution, though.

Comment: Ahhh those crafty bastards! I did consider feeding the src through an iframe, but I decided it wasn't worth crippling my site for a minor cosmetic upgrade. Perhaps eventually apple will update the older uglier skin for embedded files, and this won't be a problem.